# Trying to use a different variable that I have already declared in a different .java file in my new file

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

This is probably a simple fix or issue, but I am new to java and not sure how to do it. I have a web service that I am creating and a bunch of java files that I have with different data inputs. I want to be able to use the variables already defined in my other java files in my new file. Below you will see my code. For example on the first part of code, SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier is a column name in my MySQL database, along with a name already declared in other java files. How do I use the different variables that I have already declared in my other webserivce .java files?

Thanks for all your help!

```
package org.example.www.newwsdlfile3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JavaMYSQL  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


getConnection(); 

String sql = "INSERT INTO tableName values(':SponsorOrganiationalIdentifier', ':AgencyPersonGUID',':PersonID')";
String mySponsorID ="";
mySponsorID = "local"
sql = sql.replace(":SponsorOrganizationIdentifier", );
System.out.println(sql);

    String AgencyGUID =""
    AgencyGUID = 
    sql = sql.replace(:AgencyPersonGUID, )
    System.out.println(sql)

    String PersonIdent
    PersonIdent = 
    sql = sql.replace(:PersonID,)
    System.out.println(sql)


}
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
try{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchangeinformation";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "admin";
    Class.forName(driver);

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    return conn;
} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

return null;
}
```

}

Comment: If that variable has getters then call it by using the get function name or else you can import the other file and access the variable provided variable is defined at class level and it it public/default(assuming both the classes are in same package)

Answer (score 0):

If you have constant data like column names, consider creating a class then defining them as static final class data.

For example:

```
    class TestClass {
       public static final String MY_COLUMN_NAME = "COLUMN_NAME";
    }
```

Then you can access this variable in another class using `TestClass.MY_COLUMN_NAME` .

If the data is not final (constant) then this becomes a more complicated problem which is solved by writing a correctly structured program.